# Windows - Domain permissions to change time and date

Tags: windows, permissions, batch-file, active-directory

I have a batch file (not written by me) which lets users in across the company network reset their time and date so that they have the correct time.

This is the code:

```
@echo off

cd psexec
psexec -u DOMAIN\administrator -p PASSWORD net time /set /y
```

As you can see, this was absolutely an atrocious idea, since any user could open the file and read the network administrator's account password. Luckily, we had already changed the password when I discovered this code.

Since this is a useful file (but there's no way I will leave the administrator password just lying around), is there a way in Active Directory to grant a specific user *only* the permission to change time and date, so that it can only be used for that purpose?

Comment: Why is there even any reason to change time and date and not just setup NTP use for Windows?

Comment: @Seth Because it would require every computer to be configured manually, wouldn't it? Using such a batch would allow users to do it themselves, without having to give them dangerous credentials. Plus, the same permissions I asked for in the question could be used with W32tm to synchronise with the domain server

Comment: Configured manually? No it wouldn't. Not only do you have Group Policy allowing configuration to be "pushed out", joined Windows workstations even try to get time from the AD DC *by default*. If that isn't happening, something is already *mis*configured.

Comment: @grawity Well I hadn't considered that eventuality. I'll look into it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer, but:

- Windows normally uses NTP by default, and domain-joined Windows workstations generally use their domain controller as the NTP time server *by default.* So make sure the DCs themselves are synchronized (they can get their time from the global pool), their NTP port isn't firewalled off, and so on.
- If for some reason that's not happening, you can [push configuration](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nepapfe/2013/03/01/its-simple-time-configuration-in-active-directory/) using AD "Group Policy" across all your computers at once, e.g. if you want them to use the global NTP pool directly.
- If that doesn't work, you can use Group Policy to deploy a "login script", which can run either during user logins, or immediately after the PC boots up.
- If *that* doesn't work, you can grant `SeSystemtimePrivilege` to regular users, or for example to the special `INTERACTIVE` identifier. Again, use Group Policy for this, although it's also available locally via `secpol.msc` – in both cases it's called "Privileges → Change the system time".
- The last point above directly answers your original question about granting time-changing privileges to a user. But I'm not sure whether it's worth creating a *separate* account just for that (instead of letting users set time directly) – after all, everyone can find its password in your batch file *anyway*.

Comment: I have just discovered that our PDC and secondary DC are about 5 minutes apart from eachother. Is there any way synchronising the secondary one with w32tm could cause problems/errors?

Comment: No, it should be fine. All DCs should be automatically synchronising anyway. (Perhaps from `pool.ntp.org`.)